# Map entire network server to drive?

Tags: networking, samba, network-drive

I have a samba server with about 10 different shares on it.  I know you can map one of these shares to a drive, but could I just map the entire network server (showing each share) to a drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to mapping a drive in Windows, no.  Windows only permits you to map a single network share to a drive.  (On Linux it is possible to create a mount point for an entire server's shares using automount.)

As a workaround, you can create one network share in Samba to a directory that is full of symlinks to the all the shared directories and map that.  (Just make sure you set `wide links = yes` in that share's configuration in `smb.conf`).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I guess a batch script can suffice (to create the sym links).  Seems like an odd limitation though.